# Injection in EntityListener is not (yet) supported in Quarkus. I need a workaround to acces my current User bean

Tags: jpa, quarkus

[This](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/6948) bug prevents me from injecting my CurrentUserBean into my EntityListener class. I need a way to access my userId inside that CurrentUserBean in order to implement my @PrePersist and @PreUpdate JPA hooks.

This is what I would normally do:

```
public class EntityListener {

@Inject
private CurrentUserBean currentUserBean;

@PrePersist
void onPersist(Object entity) {
    // [...]
    entity.setCreatedBy(currentUserBean.userId);
}

@PreUpdate
void onUpdate(Object entity) {
    // [...]
    entity.setUpdatedBy(currentUserBean.userId);
}
```

}

Is there another way to achieve this ? I am using a stateless service with JWT token.

Comment: Have you tried this approach https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/6948#issuecomment-581516291 ?

Comment: I had tested it, but it did not work - but for a completely different reason. I tried again and it worked. Just answer and I'll accept your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the quarkus team has not yet implemented this feature.

But in the [github issue](https://twitter.com/lavozdegalicia/status/1432697309431742472?s=20) thread is there a workaround:

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class JPAEntityListenerInjectionWorkaround {
  @Inject FooBean fooBean;
}


FooBean fooBean = CDI.current().select(FooBean.class).get();
```

By using CDI dependency lookup capabilities it is possible to include an intermediate bean and in the event listener class retrieve this bean from the context and access the information.